# Access mat-raised-button disabled attribute

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular2-hostbinding

i try to access (*read*) the `disabled` attribute of a `mat-raised-button` Button inside of a directive.

If disabled is set true, inside my directive, during `ngOnInit`, `disabled` is still `false`, but the material button is rendered as disabled (*grey*).

Button:

```
<button
  my-directive
  mat-raised-button
  [disabled]="isDisabledOrNot()" // returns true
  (click)="doSomething()>bla</button>
```

My Diective @HostBinding Attempt:

```
export class myDirective implements OnInit {
  constructor(private element: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) {}

  @HostBinding('disabled')
  disabled: any;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(`disabled:`, this.disabled); // prints false
```

I tried using the `nativeElement`:

```
export class myDirective implements OnInit {
  constructor(private element: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(`disabled:`, this.element.nativeElement.disabled); // prints false
```

And i used [some hack version](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/24006#issuecomment-981128526) involved `class.mat-button-disabled` from github issues but neither works.

I can set the disabled button using the `Renderer2` `setAttribute` method. But that doesn't work for reading.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your directive you can Inject `MatButton` class and check whether it is disabled or not

```
constructor(private button:MatButton){}
  
ngOnInit(){
    console.log(this.button.disabled);
}
```

**[Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tb76tr?file=src/app/button-overview-example.ts)**

Comment: This also works for setting the state apparently :thumbs_up_emoji:

Answer (score 2):

The `disabled` attribute of an element is somewhat special, since it doesn't actually hold the values `true` or `false`.

If it's false, `getAtrribute('disabled')` returns `null`.

If it's true, `getAtrribute('disabled')` returns   (an empty string).

That means one way to check if an element is disabled is to check whether `getAttribute('disabled')` does **not** return `null`.

In Directive form:

```
import { AfterViewInit, Directive, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[check-disabled]',
})
export class CheckDisabledDirective implements AfterViewInit {
  constructor(private readonly m_element: ElementRef<HTMLElement>) {}

  public ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    console.log(
      `Element is currently ` +
        (this.m_element.nativeElement.getAttribute('disabled') === null
          ? 'not disabled'
          : 'disabled')
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, for me that didn't work.
It always retunred `null`.
This seems to be connected to the said usage of the material button.
But thanks for the elaborate answer.

Comment: @AndreschSerj That would make sense. This is more of a general answer to the `disabled` attribute on ansy element, but it probably behaves different when another directive also modifies it. The answer with the `MatButton` probably suits your case.

Answer (score 0):

This is one hacky Solution that worked for me:

```
nativeElement.getAttribute('ng-reflect-disabled') === 'true'
```

Now i implemented the Solution provided by [Chellappan வ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73539969/532495)